# Android: google pay intent payment is not working

Tags: android, payment-gateway, android-pay, google-pay, react-native-google-pay

I am trying to launch google pay intent to transfer payment using below as a query uri.

```
upi://pay?pa=8945343422@ybl&pn=Username&mc=5499&mode=02&orgid=000000&am=1
```

And it was successfully working before and currently it has stopped working suddenly and don't know what is the issue.

I have also tried and followed information available in the document.
https://developers.google.com/pay/india/api/android/in-app-payments

But it is also not working.

Can anyone please help for this?